# How to make current option active in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make the current option active and disable the others? I was trying this: https://jsfiddle.net/jpr33wnn/2/

I'm new to jQuery and getting stuck. Please tell if doing it wrong. Thanks.

```
<div class="col-lg-2 inner" id="dropdown1-parent">
    <h6 class="right list-item">Hendrik de Zeeuw</h6>
</div>
<div class="dropdown" id="dropdown1" style="display:none;">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <p class="dropdown-header">
            Gegevens wijzijen
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-2 inner" id="dropdown2-parent">
    <h6 class="right list-item">Hendrik de Zeeuw</h6>
</div>
<div class="dropdown" id="dropdown2" style="display:none;">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <p class="dropdown-header">
            Gegevens wijzijen
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.bg {
    color: red;
}
```

```js
(function() {
    var object = {
        dropdown1: $('#dropdown1'),
        dropdown2: $('#dropdown2'),
        dropdown1parent: function() {
            if (object.dropdown1.is(':hidden')) {
                object.dropdown1.show();
            }
        },
        dropdown2parent: function() {
            if (object.dropdown2.is(':hidden')) {
                object.dropdown2.show();
            }
        }
    }

    $('#dropdown1-parent').on('click', function() {
        $(this).addClass('bg');
        object.dropdown1parent(); 
    });

    $('#dropdown2-parent').on('click', function() {
        $(this).addClass('bg');
        object.dropdown2parent(); 
    });
})();
```

Comment: wrap the inner code in the IIFE with doc ready block. Infact you dont need the IIFE syntax for it. you just do this in the doc ready block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed your markup little bit like:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-2 inner ddparent" data-target='dropdown1' id="dropdown1-parent">
     <h6 class="right list-item">Hendrik de Zeeuw</h6>
</div>
<div class="dropdown" id="dropdown1" style="display:none;">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <p class="dropdown-header">Gegevens wijzijen</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Added a class name `'ddparent'` to the parent and `'dropdown'` to the dropdowns div and an attribute `data-target` to target the specific ones.

Is this you want:

```
$(function () {
    $('.ddparent').on('click', function () {
        var target = $(this).data('target');
        $(this).addClass('bg').siblings('.ddparent').removeClass('bg');
        $('#'+target).show().siblings('.dropdown').hide();
    });
});
```

[An updated fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/jpr33wnn/10/)

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your code by the use of common classes and DRY principles. This completely negates the need to both maintain an object to store the references to the individually identified dropdown and related parent elements. It also means that a single click handler can work for any number of dropdowns. Try this:

```
$(function () {
    $('.dropdown-parent').click(function () {
        var $parent = $(this);
        $parent.toggleClass('bg').siblings().removeClass('bg');

        var $dropdown = $parent.next('.dropdown');
        $('.dropdown').not($dropdown).hide();
        $dropdown.toggle($dropdown.is(':hidden'));
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-2 inner dropdown-parent">
     <h6 class="right list-item">Hendrik de Zeeuw</h6>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <p class="dropdown-header">Gegevens wijzijen</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jpr33wnn/7/)